# Mostar datos INT convertidos de VARCHAR en vista de SQL SERVER 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy creando una vista en la que convierto un dato VARCHAR en INT pero al hacer un SELECT a la vista me da un error diciendo que la conversion del tipo VARCHAR a INT desborda la columna

```
CREATE VIEW GCG_SACLIE_SMS
AS
SELECT
CodClie as Codigo,
  SUBSTRING(Descrip,1, CHARINDEX(' ', Descrip) ) AS Nombre,
  CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(Telef)),'+',''),'-',''),' ','')) AS Telefono
FROM
  SACLIE
```

Comment: qué versión de SQL Server?, por otro lado, si desborda un `int` trata con un `bigint`. En general, no se usa mucho convertir teléfonos a tipos de tatos numéricos, qué pasa si empiezan con un cero?

Comment: Los numeros de telefonos, por mas que tengan numeros, no son numeros... hay numeros de telefonos realmente largos que no deberian ser tratados como numeros.. o acaso vas a hacer operaciones matematicas con ellos?

Comment: es en SQL server 2014, y puedo guardarlos en varchar pero lo hago como metodo de seguridad para evitar caracteres fuera de lo numero, por esa misma razon uso el replace y no puedo usar bigint porque comienzan por 0

Comment: `bigint` es como `int`, solo que tiene un rango más extendido (64 vs 32 bits). En otras palabras, si con `bigint` te da problema que empiecen con `0`, con `int` vas a tener exactamente el mismo problema.

Answer (score 1):

## ¿Qué es un desbordamiento de entero?

Un número entero es representado en una computadora como una secuencia de bits (`0` y `1`).  Los tipos de números enteros se representan en una cantidad determinada de bits, lo cual determina el rango de números que pueden representarse en ellos. Así, un `byte`, que son 8 bits, puede representar desde el `0` hasta el `255`, ya que `255` es una secuencia de 8 unos: `11111111`. Para representar números mayores, se necesita más bits.

Si quisieramos soportar números negativos, los límites se *corren* y se puede representar desde `-128` hasta `127`.

Encontrarás más información en los artículos [*integer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)) e [*integer overflow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) (en inglés).

Tomando en cuenta esto, el desbordamiento del tipo de dato se da porque estás tratando de convertir una cadena que contiene un número mayor al soportado por el tipo al que estás tratando de convertir.

En el caso del tipo `int`, que es un entero de 32 bits, puede representar números entre `-2 147 483 648` y `2 147 483 647`.

Este script:

```
select convert(int, '2147483647');
select convert(int, '2147483648');
```

Produce esta salida:

```
-----------
2147483647

(1 row affected)

-----------
Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The conversion of the varchar value '2147483648' overflowed an int column.
```

Como puedes ver, la primera conversión tiene éxito, mientras la segunda desborda el tipo de dato y produce un error.

## ¿Qué hacer al respecto?

### Cambio de tipo de dato

Para superar este problema, puedes convertir a un tipo de dato que tenga un rango mayor. Una opción es `bigint` que es un entero de 64 bits. El rango de este tipo de dato va de `-9 223 372 036 854 775 808` a `9 223 372 036 854 775 807`.

El siguiente script se ejecutará sin errores:

```
select convert(bigint, '2147483647');
select convert(bigint, '2147483648');
```

Sin embargo, sigues teniendo límites:

```
select convert(bigint, '9223372036854775807');
select convert(bigint, '9223372036854775808');
```

Resulta en:

```
--------------------
9223372036854775807

(1 row affected)


--------------------
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint.
```

### Continuar a pesar del error

Puedes tomar medidas para que la consulta continúe procesando a pesar del error, utilizando la función `try_convert()`, en lugar de `convert()`. Esta función devolverá `null` si ha ocurrido un error durante la conversión:

Esta consulta:

```
select try_convert(int, '2147483648') as numero;
```

Produce esta salida:

```
numero
-----------
NULL

(1 row affected)
```

### Para mayor robustez, combina ambas:

Soporta los números más grandes que sea posible y continúa a pesar de los errores:

```
select try_convert(bigint, '2115465798798483648') as numero;
select try_convert(bigint, '22115465798798483648') as numero;
```